# How do I resolve a circular reference between union cases?

Tags: f#

**How do I resolve a circular reference between union cases?**

```
type ModuleInfo = | Author of Name
                  | Section of Section
                  | Duration of Duration
                  | Url of string
```

**I receive the following error:**

> The type 'Section' is not defined.

**Here's the code:**

```
module ManageModule.Entities

type FirstName = FirstName of string
type LastName = LastName of string

type Name = | First of FirstName
            | Last of LastName
            | Suffix of string option

type Duration = | Hours of int
                | Minutes of int
                | Seconds of int

type ModuleInfo = | Author of Name
                  | Section of Section
                  | Duration of Duration
                  | Url of string

type Module = Module of ModuleInfo
type Modules = Modules of ModuleInfo list

type Section = | Introduction of Module
               | Conclusion of Module
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `and` keyword:

```
type ModuleInfo = 
  | Author of Name
  | Section of Section
  | Duration of Duration
  | Url of string

and Module = Module of ModuleInfo
and Modules = Modules of ModuleInfo list

and Section = 
  | Introduction of Module
  | Conclusion of Module
```